# asp.net mvc dataannotation spacing issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, regex

this is my group annotation attributes

```
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9 _]*$", ErrorMessage = "Cannot Contains other characters ")]
    public string vcr_GroupName { get; set; }
```

i want to allow only two spaces in my textbox in regular expression  ,how would i do that

Comment: i have maxlength=50 but the problem is that if you 50 spaces then it will bypass all the validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent 50 spaces, then just trim the content and make sure it's non blank?

Anyway, note that this: `[a-zA-Z0-9 _]` is written shorter as `[\w ]`

To use regex to only allow two spaces maximum, you can do:

```
^\w+(?: \w+){0,2}$
```

(The `(?: )` part is a non-capturing group, whilst the `{0,2}` says repeat 2 or 1 or 0 times.)

This will also require that the first and last characters are not spaces.

(You might want something slightly different depending on your exact rules.)